# Is there a way to access string value from a string pointer receiver within it's own method?

Tags: string, go, pointers

I wish to do this:

```
type StateSyncError string

func (se *StateSyncError) Error() string {
    return "state sync error: " + se
}
```

which fails due to `invalid operation: "state sync error: " + se (mismatched types untyped string and *StateSyncError)`.

Is it possible to do somehow? I had hopes of `~` working since it should look at underlying type, but to no avail. Should I just use a struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dereference](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Address_operators) the pointer and use a type [conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
func (se *StateSyncError) Error() string {
    return "state sync error: " + string(*se)
}
```

Testing it:

```
var se StateSyncError = "foo"
fmt.Println(se.Error())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ZfDbd_VUAFn)):

```
state sync error: foo
```